# How to compile PHP as a static binary on MacOS?

Tags: php

I'm attempting to compile PHP from source on MacOS.  I'm using the `--enable-static` configure option to build static libraries like this:

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-all
make
```

While this produces a working binary, if I inspect the binary with `otool` I can see that it's using two shared libraries, `libresolv.9.dylib` and `libSystem.B.dylib`:

```
$ otool -L sapi/cli/php   
sapi/cli/php:
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
```

Is there any way to statically link these libraries?

Comment: This is gotta be a duplicate. I know how to answer this for GLibc. Basically, you can't, unless you want to ensure that your binary **does not work**.

Comment: Why is the C tag used?

Comment: @WeatherVane basically it is a C/C++ linking question and a generic one really.

Answer (score 2):

After researching this it sounds like it isn't possible or desirable to statically link `libresolv` and `libSystem`.

`libSystem` contains libc among other libraries. `libresolv` contains DNS functions such as `res_init`.  Both are provided by MacOS.  MacOS [does not support static binaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1118/_index.html).

Since these libraries are always available on MacOS it's ok to use them as a shared library.

If you need to support older versions of MacOS you can use the `-mmacosx-version-min` linker flag:

```
LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.7" ./configure --enable-static --disable-all
LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.7" make
```

You can confirm it worked by using `otool -l` and checking for `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX`.